# When working with Apple definition of UTIs, what is different between "public.movie" and "public.video"?

Tags: macos, avkit, uti, nsopenpanel

I am importing movies using NSOpenPanel.  You can set the allowedFileTypes to either "public.movie" and "public.video" UTI. When you do this, you can select a movie file on the desktop or one stored in Photos or TV app (library).  So, what is the diffence beween the two settings? The UTI document implies "video" is subclass of "movie", but they seem to have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

**.video** should include the graphics, but no sound. The **.movie** should provide both the graphics & sound. Click here for more from [Apple UTI's](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1)

[image]

Comment: The linked document disagrees with what you said. `.movie` is the base type for `.video` (and various other types). So, `.movie` can't have stricter requirements than `.video`, or `.video` wouldn't conform. `.movie` **may** have audio but doesn't require it.

Comment: @KenThomases - video conforms to movie & only has sound. I added a pic of the chart from the link.

Comment: Right, but you claim that `.movie` "**should** provide **both** the graphics & sound" (emphasis added), but sound is optional. If it were required, then `.video` could not "be a" `.movie`.